# How to load reference data in Spring batch

Tags: database, spring-batch

I use Spring batch in my application and I need to load a reference table from database in order to use it during the processing stage. This table is only key-value pairs of `error_code` and `error_msg`.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: preload with a JobListener or use a DAO to access table data and make read under cache

Comment: Thanks! do u know of a good example of these?

Comment: Using a JobListener is pretty easy. For spring-cache module check for official doc

Comment: Why do you need to pre-load the data?  Why not just cache the call so you essentially lazily load it?